# Запись кириллицы в Android

Tags: java, android, utf-8

Есть два метода (оба - слегка модифицированные версии примеров из документации):

```
public void saveFile (String filePath, String FileContent){
    //Создание объекта файла.
    File fHandle = new File(filePath);
    try{
        //Если нет директорий в пути, то они будут созданы:
        if (!fHandle.getParentFile().exists())
            fHandle.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        //Если файл существует, то он будет перезаписан:
        fHandle.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fHandle);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        myOutWriter.write(FileContent);

        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("ERROR","Path " + filePath + ", " + e.toString());
    }
}

public void saveUtf8File(String filePath, String fileContent){
    Writer out = null;
    File fHandle = new File(filePath);
    try {
        if (!fHandle.getParentFile().exists())
            fHandle.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        fHandle.createNewFile();

        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(filePath), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        out.write(fileContent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Оба пишут файлы туда, куда им скажут (сначала я определяю, куда можно писать, потом пишу файл - всё как надо).

Есть два поля `EditText fileNameEditText;` и `EditText mainTextField;`- из них я беру данные - имя файла и контент - вот так:

```
String fName = fileNameEditText.getText().toString();
fName = fName.trim();
String fContent = mainTextField.getText().toString();
```

Всё бы хорошо, но есть нюанс: при сохранении файла - имя файла (на русском) отображается чудесно, а вот содержимое файла (тоже на русском) - отображается именно как иероглифы (не кракозябры), содержимое на английском в том же файле отображается нормально.

Что я делаю не так? Как записать допустим в папку Downloads (а лучше порекомендуйте куда писать текстовые файлы (utf8), особенно если директории `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` нет в системе) текстовые файлы, содержащие кириллицу?

Спасибо!

Comment: отображается чем как иерогифы? может проблема не с записью а с чтением?

Comment: Ну китайские или японские (не разбираюсь, увы), но не кракозябры (аля cp1251 -> utf8) именно иероглифы. Правда может и в просмотрщике дело - умолчальный (не помню точно как его зовут) htmlviewer андройдовский. Сейчас на машину скопирую файл - посмотрю, что в нём. Спасибо за идею.

Comment: Ага. И правда, что-то я упустил вариант, что сама читалка не может в кириллицу. На настольном компьютере всё чудесно. Спасибо.

Comment: Что это вы за самодеятельность написали?:) Просто превратите то что вы пишете в byte[], используйте FileOutputStream и пишите себе файлики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было не файле, а в том, чем я его читал.
Похоже, умолчальная читалка не умеет в кириллицу.